# Obtain Class instance of Generic interface including type parameters

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Lets say i have an Interface `GenericInterface`

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
    T get();
}
```

Now, for example, if I want to obtain a Class object of the type `Class<GenericInterface<String>>`, like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<GenericInterface<String>> aClass = ...
    }
}
```

how would I go about doing that? `GenericInterface<String>.class` doesn't work, and `GenericInterface.class` only returns a `Class<GenericInterface>`, without the type parameter. `Class.forName("GenericInterface<java.lang.String>")` also just throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. Is it even possible to obtain such an object?

Comment: See super type tokens [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-super-type-tokens)

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, because of the type erasure there's no exact representation for parameterized classes. Basically, `GenericInterface<String>.class` would be the same as `GenericInterface<Long>.class`.

On the other hand, if you really need such Class for whatever reason, there's still an (ugly) way to have it by using a double cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<GenericInterface<String>> cls = (Class<GenericInterface<String>>)(Object)GenericInterface.class;
```

Comment: It’s also possible with a single cast: `@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
Class<GenericInterface<String>> cls = (Class)GenericInterface.class;` To be used with care.